# Where is a bar, cafe, etc that shows pay-per-view UFC fights in Taichung, Taiwan?

Tags: taiwan, nightlife, sports-events, cafes, taichung

I'm in Taichung, Taiwan. One of the three biggest cities in Taiwan.

There's lots of expats, but mostly from other Asian countries from what I've seen.

Normally I would look for a sports bar on Google Maps or just Google the question and find somebody has already asked or already created a list of places for a given city.

But in this case my Google-fu is failing. Google Maps is only throwing up red herrings. Places which are already closed or look nothing like sports bars when you go to street view.

Can somebody do a better search using Chinese, or does somebody have the local knowledge?

Comment: @pnuts: No it doesn't. That would probably depend mostly on the timezone difference. What would matter most to me is if it has a cover charge or if their drinks are overpriced (-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well just after I posted this, `pnuts` indirectly helped me find a venue!

A place called ["The Uptowner" is advertising the even on their Facebook page](http://Fwww.facebook.com/theuptownertaichung/posts/1742709696003084):

[image: Grab of the Facebook page]

They mention having to book a seat, which I'm not keen on. Plus I can't tell if it might be pricey.

So I'm still open to alternative places, but at least I've found one. Thanks pnuts!

Comment: well, given that they have to pay per visitor, having to book a seat seems a logical consequence...

Comment: @jwenting: Hmm I haven't had to book before in Australia or Vietnam. I have no idea how the places have to pay. I've just turned up and purchased a beverage and found a place to sit.